# How I can put a js file in Magento product page

Tags: xml, magento

I made a magento theme and have the following code in the file local.xml

**CODE XML:**

```
<catalog_product_view>
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="addItem">
                    <type>skin_js</type>
                    <name>js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js</name>
                </action>
                <action method="addCss">
                    <stylesheet>css/prettyPhoto.css</stylesheet>
                </action>
            </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

When I run this code is not added in head files of js and css files

if I go in the file `base/default/layout/catalog.xml` and add the following code works.

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>css/prettyPhoto.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
</reference>
```

can you tell me please which is why it does not work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your local.xml file?  Are you sure that the theme is enabled, and have you cleared cache? Do other updates show that you make in `local.xml`?

Comment: the cache is disabled, local.xml go as things go from file .. it just does not work

Comment: And in `catalog.xml` you're in the `<catalog_product_view>` node?